# Java question about super

Tags: java

If A extends B, then I know I can user super.*** to access B's method.

What if A extends B and B extends C, how to access C's method from A?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a method is overriden in B, you cannot "bypass" it.

It's not possible even when using reflection (not in any way known to me).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you *can't* bypass overriding using reflection.

Comment: @Stephen. Agreed. But you can never be sure whether there is some JVM-specific helper class that does that. Not that I've seen anything like this. Edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

not sure but I think you can do super.super.methodA ?

Comment: Tried, there is not super.super